# "500 - An error has occurred" in Joomla, when attemping to login in backend

Tags: joomla, backend, administration

When I attemp to login in the backend using the right login of the Super User i get an error page "500 - An error has occurred."

I have changed the Super User password by PhpMyAdmin and the error remains.

I have installed Joomla 2.5 installed.

Answer (score 5):

First you have change folder permission to 775 for the following folders:

cache, logs, tmp & administrator/cache

Then go to: configuration.php

```
find code:
$log_path = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$tmp_path = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX';

and change code into:
$log_path = './logs';
$tmp_path = './tmp';
```

Comment: this is not going to work. I have this problem for several month and I am sure that it's not caused by folder permissions or log and temp path. I have no solution right now. maybe in future

Comment: If this alone doesn't work, go to phpmyadmin, select all the tables and select repair from the dropdown.