# Joomla Backend Login Error "500 - An error has occurred."

Tags: joomla, backend

I've just inherited a Joomla site that I didn't create and now no one can login to the backend. Whenever I try to login in I get this...

```
500 - An error has occurred.
```

I already tried the suggested fix in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208594/500-an-error-has-occurred-in-joomla-when-attemping-to-login-in-backend)

Comment: It's most likely that you are using wrong login and/or password.

Comment: That would not account for no one being able to log in I don't think.

Comment: Can you login to the front end?

Comment: It actually was a wrong username and password case like @di3sel said. I was given the wrong username and password and another user just forgot their password but thought they knew it... Thanks anyways guys